# Is there a way to iterate over nested list in parallel?

Tags: java, loops, kotlin, stream, nested-lists

I have this input in a `HashMap<Int,List<ClassName>>`

**1=[100 : 1.0, 233 : 0.9,....n],**

**2=[24 : 1.0, 13 : 0.92,....n],**

**3=[5 : 1000.0, 84 : 901.0,....n],**

**4=[24 : 900.0, 12 : 850.0...n],**

.
.
.
**//n number if entries**

I want to convert it to
**[100 : 1.0 ,24 : 1.0 ,5 : 1000.0 ,34 : 900 , 233 : 0.9, 13 : 0.92,84 : 901.0 ,12 : 850.0]**

Basically pick out the same index of each list. I'm using **Java** and code may be really helpful. Thanks:)

Comment: You've got to give it a try and the question still remains unclear in terms of what your class model is and what is the type of output you're expecting. Is it a `HashMap` or `List<ClassName>`?

Comment: Additionally, your example repeats the key `24`, and seems to completely ignore this in the 'I want to convert it to' section and go with the 'first'.  Is this the expected behaviour?  'First' becomes harder to track if you're iterating in parallel.

Comment: If you want an answer in Java, why is this tagged with Kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an `Iterator` for each `List`, then pull one value from each, repeat pull until done.

Something like this:

```
public final class ClassName {
    private final int a;
    private final double b;
    public ClassName(int a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.a + " : " + this.b;
    }
}
```

```
Map<Integer, List<ClassName>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(1, Arrays.asList(new ClassName(100, 1.0), new ClassName(233, 0.9)));
map.put(2, Arrays.asList(new ClassName(24, 1.0), new ClassName(13, 0.92)));
map.put(3, Arrays.asList(new ClassName(5, 1000.0), new ClassName(84, 901.0)));
map.put(4, Arrays.asList(new ClassName(24, 900.0), new ClassName(12, 850.0)));
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
```

```
List<ClassName> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<Iterator<ClassName>> iterators = map.values().stream()
        .map(List::iterator).collect(Collectors.toList());
while (iterators.stream().anyMatch(Iterator::hasNext))
    iterators.stream().filter(Iterator::hasNext).map(Iterator::next).forEach(result::add);

System.out.println(result);
```

Note: Changed to use a `LinkedHashMap` so the result would be in defined order.

*Output*

```
1=[100 : 1.0, 233 : 0.9]
2=[24 : 1.0, 13 : 0.92]
3=[5 : 1000.0, 84 : 901.0]
4=[24 : 900.0, 12 : 850.0]
```

```
[100 : 1.0, 24 : 1.0, 5 : 1000.0, 24 : 900.0, 233 : 0.9, 13 : 0.92, 84 : 901.0, 12 : 850.0]
```